# Map JSON with specific class using httpClient and RxJS map

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have some JSON data from an external source : https://www.guidle.com/m_3GbJsF.

I'm using HttpClient to get the data and RxJS map to process them. So here is my Service :

```js
    getEvents() { 
          return this.http.get<any[]>(this.baseUrl)
            .pipe(
               map((data: any) => {
                 return data.groupSet[0].offers;
               }),
             );
     }
```

The problem is at this step... I want to map JSON fields with my object Event and then put it in an Array. For example :

```
Event.id = id
Event.name = bpName
Event.startDate = schedules.dates[0].startDate
```

Here's my way of doing that :

```js
mapEvents() {
    const events = this.getEvents();
      const eventsProcessed = events
         .pipe(
             map(({id, bpName, schedules.dates[0].startDate}) => new Event(id, bpName, schedules.dates[0].startDate)),
             toArray()
     );

return eventsProcessed;
}
```

But it's not working and I don't know how to use RxJS to achieve my goal (if it's possible).

I certainly don't understand correctly RxJS and Observable but after hours and hours working on this little code and the official doc, I think a need somebody help.

Maybe there is an other solution so I am open to any other proposal.

Thanks a lot !

---

I think the problem comes from :

```js
    getEvents() { 
          return this.http.get<any[]>(this.baseUrl)
            .pipe(
               map((data: any) => {
                 return data.groupSet[0].offers;
               }),
             );
     }
```

It returns an Array.

[Picture : results in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5h5J.png)

If I try with this, it works :

```
dataTest = from([
        {
            id: 1058907,
            bpName: 'Amt für Kultur',
            schedules: {
                dates: [
                    {
                        startDate: "18.06.2019",
                    }
                ]
            },

        },
        {
            id: 1058909,
            bpName: 'Kath. Pfarramt St. Michael',
            schedules: {
                dates: [
                    {
                        startDate: "19.06.2019",
                    }
                ]
            },

        },
    ]);
```

[Picture : result in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbtGn.png)

Is it something that I have to do to change the return of getEvents() to be the same type that my dataTest?

Comment: Nothing to do with RxJs. `map(({id, bpName, schedules}) => new Event(id, bpName, schedules.dates[0].startDate)),`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As previously mentioned, the issue is that your http get request emits a simple item which is an array of elements. So a simple map is attempting to map the *array* not the array elements.

I map to a class using code like this:

```
  productsClassInstance$ = this.http.get<ProductClass[]>(this.productsUrl)
    .pipe(
      map(products => products.map(product => {
        const productInstance: ProductClass = Object.assign(new ProductClass(), {
          ...product,
          price: product.price * 1.5
        });
        return productInstance;
      })),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
```

I follow three steps:

1) I map the array returned from the http get (see the first `map` statement).

2) I use the *array* map method to map each element in the array (see `products.map`)

3) I transform each array element, creating a new instance of the class (see the body of the `products.map` arrow function).

Hope this helps.